# How to prove that $p^{e-f}\mid\binom{n}{t}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ a prime odd number, $e,f,n,t\in\mathbb{N}$ such that: $2\leq t\leq n$, $p^{e}|n$, and $p^f\mid t$ but $p^{f+1}\nmid t$ . So we have $n=p^en',t=p^ft'$ and $gcd(p,t')=1$.

I already know that $\binom{n}{t}=\frac{n}{t}\binom{n-1}{t-1}=p^{e-f}\frac{n'}{t'}\binom{n-1}{t-1}$, but I don't know how prove that  $\frac{n'}{t'}\binom{n-1}{t-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Any help or idea is well received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
\binom{n}{t} = \frac{n}{t}\binom{n - 1}{t - 1},
$$
it follows that
$$
t | n\binom{n - 1}{t - 1}.
$$
In particular,
$$
t^\prime | n\binom{n - 1}{t - 1} = p^en^{\prime}\binom{n - 1}{t - 1}.
$$
But $gcd(t^\prime, p^e) = 1$. Thus
$$
t^\prime|n^{\prime}\binom{n - 1}{t - 1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks by the explanation, now I can go ahead with my study of Galois Rings with confidence.